# A variable composed of standardized scores does not necessarily have M=0, SD=1?

Tags: standardization

If you standardize scores using 10 cases(group 1), and standardize scores using another 10 cases (group 2), you select 5 scores from each group, and compose a variable. Does this variable have mean equal 0, sd=1?

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely. Once the values are standardized so that mean=0 and sd=1 within a group, then they are only standardized within the context of that group. It'd be worth running this code a few times in R to see what happens in your situation:

```
#Generate two groups of standardized data
group1 = rnorm(10,mean=0,sd=1)
group2 = rnorm(10,mean=0,sd=1)

#Choose the first five from both groups
group1_set = head(group1, 5)
group2_set = head(group2, 5)

#Create new variable
newgroup = c(group1_set, group2_set)

#Check whether mean is 0 and sd is 1
mean(newgroup)
sd(newgroup)
```